# Can't write to known_hosts

Tags: permission, filesystem

I reinstalled my system and recovered the `known_hosts` file with Time Machine. And now I have no longer permission to write in said file.

I have set Read & Write for me,staff and everybody on said file. But that doesn't change anything.

What could be the problem there?

Output:

```
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 username  staff  17773 14 Mär 14:44 known_hosts
```

Output 2:

```
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 mtdesign  staff  17773 14 Mär 14:44 known_hosts
com.apple.TextEncoding     11 
com.apple.finder.copy.source.checksum#N     4 
com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot     50 
com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot     50 
com.apple.quarantine       23
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -la known_hosts` so we can see the permissions?

Comment: Since it has extended attributes, please issue the comand `ls -la@ known_hosts`

Comment: @alan does this help?

Comment: @KSPR The standard permissions for (the folder .ssh and) known_hosts are 600.

Comment: I don't see anything there that should prevent you from writing the file (assuming `username` is just what you put to obfuscate you actual username). Try writing to the file with the command `echo "# Delete this line" >> known_hosts` and let me know if you can write to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the file has extended attributes and on a fresh install doesn't I'd start by removing them, `xattr -c ~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

When you say you can't write to the file, do you mean directly or via `ssh` adding a host? I'd try `cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts` to make sure you can open it. Then you might try `cp ~/.ssh/known_hosts ~/Documents/known_hosts` and `echo "Delete this line" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` to see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

Trough endless trial and error I found this to be solving the problem:

```
sudo chmod -N .ssh/known_hosts
```

I have no idea what it does. But this made it writable through the terminal. When I connect somewhere via ssh and the prompt is asking me if I want to add the key to the *known_hosts* file and I hit yes, then it works. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: `-N: Removes the ACL from the named file(s)`!

Comment: Yep, @klanomath. Same thing as `xattr -c` :)